How to Block all internet acccess except few whitelist websites in binddns
i have bind9 dns running on ubuntu. default configuation present. i want to block all internet access to my clients excpets some white listed websites. some body help please. i have tried RPZ and forwarder but not succeeded

The bind is a DNS server, it can't block internet access. It could be used to block (DNS) name resolution, but your client still can access the internet.

To block all Internet access except for specific whitelisted websites in BIND DNS, configure an Access Control List (ACL) to deny all by default and allow only specific domains. Use the ACL entries to define the domains you want to allow and deny the rest. This allows access to only the whitelisted websites, effectively blocking all others.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
